# How to display all rows in a data frame

Tags: c#, dataframe

I am using Microsoft.Data.Analysis in C# for data analysis. I built a console application and created a dataframe using statement:

```
DataFrame df = new DataFrame(time, x, y);
```

df has 106 rows. I tried to display df in the console by:

```
Console.WriteLine(df);
```

But I only got to see the first 25 rows. Is there a way to show all the rows in the console? I know "display.max_rows" can be used in pandas, is there an equivalent setting in C# DataFrame?

Comment: Note that `DateFrame.ToString()` [says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.analysis.dataframe.tostring?view=ml-dotnet-preview) "A preview of the contents of this DataFrame as a string." It's also a preview API.

Comment: @gunr2171 Thank u. I've tried Console.WriteLine(df.ToString()), but it gave me the exact same result as Console.WriteLine(df) (only 25 rows were shown)

Answer (score -1):

I a using the custom PrettyPrint() extension method to improve DataFrame readability.
Please look into this extension method , It may be useful to format and display DataFrame Data : More documentation on dataFrames and their difefrent option in here [Pretty DataFrame Formatting](https://swharden.com/blog/2022-05-01-dotnet-dataframe/)

Below code is to call the Method to display FataFrame data:

```
df.PrettyPrint()
```

Below is the Method code :

```
using Microsoft.Data.Analysis;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ApacheOrcDemo
{
    internal static class PrettyPrinters
    {
        public static void PrettyPrint(this DataFrame df) => Console.WriteLine(PrettyText(df));
        public static string PrettyText(this DataFrame df) => ToStringArray2D(df).ToFormattedText();
    public static string ToMarkdown(this DataFrame df) => ToStringArray2D(df).ToMarkdown();

    public static void PrettyPrint(this DataFrameRow row) => Console.WriteLine(Pretty(row));
    public static string Pretty(this DataFrameRow row) => row.Select(x => x?.ToString() ?? string.Empty).StringJoin();
    private static string StringJoin(this IEnumerable<string> strings) => string.Join(" ", strings.Select(x => x.ToString()));

    private static string[,] ToStringArray2D(DataFrame df)
    {
        string[,] strings = new string[df.Rows.Count + 1, df.Columns.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < df.Columns.Count; i++)
            strings[0, i] = df.Columns[i].Name;

        for (int i = 0; i < df.Rows.Count; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < df.Columns.Count; j++)
                strings[i + 1, j] = df[i, j]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

        return strings;
    }

    private static int[] GetMaxLengthsByColumn(this string[,] strings)
    {
        int[] maxLengthsByColumn = new int[strings.GetLength(1)];

        for (int y = 0; y < strings.GetLength(0); y++)
            for (int x = 0; x < strings.GetLength(1); x++)
                maxLengthsByColumn[x] = Math.Max(maxLengthsByColumn[x], strings[y, x].Length);

        return maxLengthsByColumn;
    }

    private static string ToFormattedText(this string[,] strings)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new();
        int[] maxLengthsByColumn = GetMaxLengthsByColumn(strings);

        for (int y = 0; y < strings.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < strings.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                sb.Append(strings[y, x].PadRight(maxLengthsByColumn[x] + 2));
            }
            sb.AppendLine();
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }


    private static string ToMarkdown(this string[,] strings)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new();
        int[] maxLengthsByColumn = GetMaxLengthsByColumn(strings);

        for (int y = 0; y < strings.GetLength(0); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < strings.GetLength(1); x++)
            {
                sb.Append(strings[y, x].PadRight(maxLengthsByColumn[x]));
                if (x < strings.GetLength(1) - 1)
                    sb.Append(" | ");
            }
            sb.AppendLine();

            if (y == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < strings.GetLength(1); i++)
                {
                    int bars = maxLengthsByColumn[i] + 2;
                    if (i == 0)
                        bars -= 1;
                    sb.Append(new String('-', bars));

                    if (i < strings.GetLength(1) - 1)
                        sb.Append("|");
                }
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

}